# Leverage MVC Client-Side Validation when using Ajax Post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

It's my first `asp.net mvc` project and I am trying to build a view that displays a list of `countries`. on `double click` it changes the input from `readonly` to false to enable editing and on `keypress` or `blur` it saves the changes.

Now, `server-side validation` is working but `client-side` is not. I am not sure is it because I don't have a form tag or it can't be done or needs manual hook-ups.

CountryModel:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MinLength(4)]
    [MaxLength(60)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string Name
    { get; set; }

}
```

Country Controller Action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Country country)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.Entry(country).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            //return
            return Json("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            //return
            return Json("Failed");
        }
    }
```

Country View:

```
@model IEnumerable<Models.Country>

<h2>Manage Countries</h2>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            Options
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "grid-input", data_input_mode = "read", data_model_id = item.CountryId } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

Scripts.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".grid-input").attr("readonly", true);

    $(".grid-input").dblclick(function () {
    var elem = $(this);

    if (elem.attr("data-input-mode") == "read") {
        elem.attr("data-input-mode", "edit");
        elem.removeAttr("readonly");

        //Remove selection when mode changes from read to edit only
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();

        //bind blur and keypress to attempt saving data on focusout or enter press
        elem.on("blur keypress", function (e) {

            if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.type == "blur") {

                //Stop Bubbling
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                //Enable Readonly To Avoid Edits While Saving
                $(this).attr("data-input-mode", "read");
                $(this).attr("readonly", "true");

                //Get Country ID & Name
                var _countryId = $(this).attr("data-model-id");
                var _countryName = $(this).val();

                //Validate
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Country/Save',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        country: {
                            CountryId: _countryId,
                            Name: _countryName
                        }
                    }),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data == "Success") {
                            console.log("Saved!");
                        } else {
                            elem.attr("data-input-mode", "edit");
                            elem.removeAttr("readonly");

                            console.log("Error occurs on the Database level!");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        console.log("An error has occured!!!");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Client side validation (using `jquery.validate.unobtrusive`) will not work unless you have a form. And you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, To confirm my understanding. Client-side validation will only work within a form tag and I can't generate multiple form tags. So basically to achieve this `View` I need to automatically generate validation tags and pass it from the `ModelState` to the client ? If so do you have any recommendations on how to do so or if my `View` is not practical ?

Comment: Why are you not just generating the inputs inside a form using a `for` loop or `EditorTemplate` and submitting all the changes in one action. 1/10 of the code, better performance, better uer experience and everything works out of the box. Or if your expecting users to edit only a few of many, then use a modal form and ajax to submit it.

Comment: System users will hardly change these. and I wanted to build a simple interface for editing and adding countries if needed. so I think the first option is not suitable. I will try the second option and also explore the first one, I saw some posts about multiple form tags in a single view!